# asp:textbox displays question marks instead of Kanji/Japanese characters characters

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page which consumes a Siebel webservice and gets Kanji characters from Siebel on demand. This shows as a series of question marks in the aspx textbox. This cannot be a data error from the backend as the other applications get proper kanji characters from Siebel. Also, I have installed East Asian languages from control panel and added [ja-Jp] language under Languages tab of Internet Explorer 7. also, I have added 
    **globalization requestEncoding="Shift-JIS" responseEncoding="Shift-JIS"** 
to my web.config and have also tried changing 'Shift-JIS' to 'utf-8' in the above line, but no difference. I have also saved my aspx page and its code-behind pages with Unicode (utf-8 with signature) encoding, but find no change in the characters displayed in the textbox.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

From server side, all you need to do is that make sure that you get a .NET string from a web-service with correct data and assign the string to the text-box.

This is obviously the issue at client side - most likely cause is that you have chosen a wrong font for your web page/text-box (either via your CSS or in browser settings). If font does not support the unicode character then it will show ?. So try changing font.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Vinay. I have chosen 'Arial Unicode MS' as Webpage font and 'MS Gothic' as plain text font under Fonts dialog of Internet Explorer. Also, my css class has Arial Unicode MS. But I still see only question marks in the textbox.

Comment: @Jay, if you do the view-source for your page, what is the value that you see in your text box. Also, use utf-8 as requestEncoding & responeEncoding.

Comment: Thanks for your time Vinay.In the page's source, there were kanji characters, and not question marks. Finally I found the solution to this problem (but not the reason). The culprit was the javascript method call  "window.showModalDialog()", and the textboxes displaying question marks were in this modal window. Once I changed this to window.open(), the kanji characters displayed correctly in the textboxes. Strange! It now works without even adding 'globalization' tag to web.config.

Comment: @Jay, its indeed strange! BTW, you don't need any globalization tag because default encoding (utf-8) should suffice to represent any Unicode characters (not only that utf-8 is widely supported encoding in browsers, toolkits, frameworks etc).

Answer (score 0):

window.open() displayed the Kanji characters which were displayed as a set of question marks earlier. However, I ran into another serious problem as window.open() is Asynchronous. In window.showModalDialog, the execution was Synchronous and thus any statement after window.ShowModalDialog() would wait till the dialog window was dismissed by the user.
So the challenge faced now was even more difficult as I had to bring synchronous behavior to window.open(), which made things more intricate.

Finally I found a solution to both the problems. I used the Javascript method escape(). This now displays kanji characters instead of question marks and more importantly this works with window.showModalDialog().

Syntax: escape()